# ALTER COLUMN equivalents in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I'm working in SQL, I find almost all the things I do with a column are related to the following four operations:

1. Add a column.
2. Remove a column.
3. Change a column type.

What is the preferred way to do these three DML operations in pandas. For example, let's suppose I am starting with the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'product': 'drink', 'brand': 'spindrift', 'id': '19'}, 
        {'product': 'cup', 'brand': None, 'id': '11'}
])
```

How would I:

- Change the `df.id` column from a string (or `object` as it says) to an `int64` ?
- Rename the column `product` to `product_type` ?
- Add a new column called 'cost' with values `[2.99, 3.99]` ?
- Remove the column called `brand` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and complete:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'product': 'drink', 'brand': 'spindrift', 'id': '19'}, 
        {'product': 'cup', 'brand': None, 'id': '11'}
])

# Change the df.id column from a string (or object as it says) to an int64 ?

df['id'] = df['id'].astype(np.int64)

# Rename the column product to product_type ?
df = df.rename(columns={'product':'prouduct_type'})

# Add a new column called 'cost' with values [2.99, 3.99] ?
df['cost'] = pd.Series([2.99, 3.99])

# Remove the column called brand ?
df = df.drop(columns='brand')
```

This functions can also be chained together. I would not recommend it as it is not fixable as above:

```py
# do all the steps above with a single line
df = df.astype({'id':np.int64},
          axis=1
       ).rename(columns={'product':'prouduct_type'}
       ).assign(cost=[2.99, 3.99]
       ).drop(columns='brand')
```

There is also another way to which you can use `inplace=True`  . This does the assignment. I don’t recommend it as it is not explicitly as the first method

```py
# Using inplace=True

df['id'].astype(np.int64, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'product':'prouduct_type'}, inplace=True)

# No change from previous
df['cost'] = pd.Series([2.99, 3.99])

# pop brand out
df.pop('brand')

print(df)
```

Comment: I am not sure if Pandas fixed the "bug" as it use not to replace the columns if axis=1 (columns-wise) was not set. Try to remove it. If it is fixed then I would say, it is a habit that I need to get over :)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform these steps like this (starting with your original data frame):

```
# add a column
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series([2.99, 3.99], name='cost')], axis=1)

# change column name
df = df.rename(columns={'product': 'product_type'})

# remove brand
df = df.drop(columns='brand')

# change data type
df['id'] = df['id'].astype('int')

print(df)

  product_type  id  cost
0        drink  19  2.99
1          cup  11  3.99
```

Comment: great, thank you -- could you explain the `concat` operation a bit more -- for example, why the `axis` argument?

Comment: `pd.concat` is not required here. You can simply use `df['cost'] = [2.99, 3.99]` .

Comment: @MayankPorwal is correct.  But concat is useful, so I thought it was worth showing.  With the default `axis=0`, concat will put one table on top of the other (like union in SQL).  With `axis=1`, concat will create a wide table, with alignment on index labels.  This alignment by index and column is central to pandas.

Answer (score 0):

you  cound do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'product': 'drink', 'brand': 'spindrift', 'id': '19'}, 
        {'product': 'cup', 'brand': None, 'id': '11'}
])
df = (df.assign(cost=[2.99, 3.99], 
               id=lambda d: d.id.astype(int))
        .drop(columns=['brand'])
        .rename({"product": 'product_type'}, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
# change datatype
>>> df['id'] = df['id'].astype('int64')
>>> df.dtypes
brand      object
id          int64
product    object
```

```
# rename column
df.rename(columns={'product': 'product_type'}, inplace=True)
>>> df
       brand  id product_type
0  spindrift  19        drink
1       None  11          cup
```

```
# create new column
df['Cost'] = pd.Series([2.99, 3.99])
>>> df
       brand  id product_type  Cost
0  spindrift  19        drink  2.99
1       None  11          cup  3.99
```

```
# drop column
>>> df.drop(['brand'], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df
   id product_type  Cost
0  19        drink  2.99
1  11          cup  3.99
```